# Dispose audio after sound has played?

Tags: c#, audio, dispose

If I play a sound with SoundPlayer or NAudio,
how can I check when the sound has played ?
Because I use this now:

```
waveOut.Play();  
waveOut.Dispose();
```

If I test this then I hear a little "click"
as expected, but I want to hear the full lenght
of the sound and then dispose it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is the `PlaybackStopped` event, but that [doesn't seem a real solution](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.nl/2011/05/naudio-and-playbackstopped-problem.html).

The problem with your code is now: the `Play` method is fire-and-forget. It starts playing and then returns the control back to your program. It runs in the background. You immediately dispose it now, which cause it to stop.

If there is no other way to get this done, I suggest to make a list of `waveOut` instances you have used and dispose them when you close and dispose your form. In that way at least the memory gets freed up.

Comment: Oke but it crashes when I'm doing stuff in the form so I think it makes no sense if I close the form that I dispose all sounds.
But I will implement this in the code.
Thanks

Comment: Can I use something like this maybe ?

SoundHOVER.Dispose();

Or:

SoundHOVER().Dispose();

I can't seem to get this right.

Comment: Disposing should only be done when the sound is done. Not any time sooner, so that is what you have to wait for. The problem is: you can't tell.

Comment: what if you be able to get duration of wav?

Comment: Possibly if it is a single play and no stops, rewinds and loops.

Comment: The project is to make a Space Invaders game and  add extra features like sounds and points and such, but the sound of my laser is 470 miliseconds) so I was thinking to add a with the total lenght of the sound ?

Comment: You could start a thread to sleep for X time and dispose it then. Of run the entire sound procedures in another thread.